# How can I disable read-only file warning in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, readonly

When you want to Edit a Read-Only file in Eclipse, a messagebox comes up asking: `"File ... is read-only. Do you wish to make it writable?"`.

[image]

How can I get rid of this messagebox and always have the editor in read-only mode when I open a read-only file?

Answer (score 1):

try

File > Properties
Under Resource > Under Attributes > un-check Read only

Works for me in eclipse Helios

Comment: Not what OP wanted, AFAICT. I also would like a way to turn off the "Would you like to make this writable?" pop up - so that permissions are honored by default. I don't want to accidentally (thoughtlessly) click "Yes" to that. Of course, when I do muck it up, @noobie's suggestion points to a simple "in-Eclipse" way of fixing it (in E-Oxygen, by un-checking as needed in the Write column). **Full Disclosure:** When I need to change (fix) permissions on more than one or two items, I usually side-step Eclipse and drop to shell CLI, e.g. `chmod a-w ...`)

Answer (score 0):

A plugin can do this. But I thought up a tricky one. Set all the files under that project as read-only, and make them only writable and controllable by Admin Group, then start eclipse without admin privilege. I've tested that the dialog won't show up.

Comment: I am working with a source controller and some of files must be set as writable.

Comment: Then is it ok to make those files as writable, and others read-only by admin group?

Answer (score 0):

I once saw a defect request against Eclipse on this issue many years ago, and it seems Eclipse developers have no plan to do it.

Also, I could not find the Eclipse plugin that StarPinkER mentioned, so in the mean time the LEAST annoying way is to **press ESC button** when the dialog show up.