# eclipse "Choose any action" popup issue for read only file, without even editing

Tags: eclipse-2020-03

I am using Eclipse version 2020-03 I don't want to use or upgrade to any other version for some reasons.
I am opening a read only file. Whenever I double click on any line it shows me the below prompt. Ideally this popup should come when I try to type any word in there. However in my case, its showing that prompt even if I select a simple word. Its weird and irritating now.

How do I fix it?
I want it to show this popup only when I try to actually edit the file.

PS:  I have checked This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322260/how-can-i-disable-read-only-file-warning-in-eclipse), but its not related to my issue.
[image]